# Converting image to data file (.dat) in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, file, converters

Is there a way in `matlab` to convert an image file `i.e; .png` to `.dat` file?

Comment: .dat is not a specific file type. It can have different formats for different programs. Do you know what format this .dat file should have?

Comment: @Molly. Thanks for your reply. I was just trying to apply fuzzy c-means from the fuzzy logic toolbox, and found that I have to read a `dat` file. Does that make sense?

Comment: You don't need a .dat file to use the fcm function. You can read in your png file using imread, possibly reshape it, and then pass it directly to fcm. I don't have that toolbox so I can't give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the format of your `.dat` file. `.dat` is not a standard extension so you can get this from somewhere or design your own writer and reader. In terms of reading the `.png` you can just use matlabs `imread('filename')` function. This will return a NxMx3 matrix of the image and RGB values.

I would suggest combining the RGB values into a single float value and then using `dlmwrite` or `csvwrite` to store it. If you want to manipulate the image first that will be up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you just kindly calrify your point:`I would suggest combining the RGB values into a single float value`?